# Archiving of data from public production server to internal archive server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, archiving

We have a web-application where - amongst other things - an detailed archive of log-data from embedded devices is kept. We want to keep this detailed data for internal analysis, but this data is not needed on the public accessible production server for longer than three months. The web-application only inserts new data, there are no updates or deletes on the detailed data.

So we want to build an archive system which gets regularly (e.g. daily) a copy of the new data from the production server (including the last three months) and then all data older then three months is removed from the production server.

Unfortunately sometimes some of our embedded devices are offline for some time (days to weeks). In this case it could happen that new data is added to the system for an already copied/archived time.

On the public production server we are using SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition, on the internal archive system we want to use SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition to benefit from partitioning and compression for the archive.

At the moment I am considering the following approaches:

1. Daily replication of data from production to archive system. When old data on production is deleted this should not be replicated to the archive system. I found an option to ignore delete operations on the replication target.
2. If there was not the requirement to also have the current data on the archive system I regularly would move all data older than a specific time to the archive system. But I have to synchronize the current data and move all old data.

   Maybe I have to use a mixed solution: Replication for synchronizing the current data between archive and production system and moving of old data to an archive table on the archive system (while replicating the deletes for the archived data from the current table to the production system).

What do you think? Do you have some recommendations or know some best practices regarding such problems? Is this topic covered elsewhere (e.g. books)?

Thank you very much in advance.

PS: I am not sure if this question should be asked here or on serverfault. Please move it if my decision posting it here was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is have your web app insert in both DBs simultaneously. This way archive is not dependent on prod db. at all.

You may also consider partitioning the prod. DB so that removing data from prod DB is easier. (But since your prod DB is standard edition, that's not an option.) In which case, you may have to delete rows from prod DB. To do the deletes, dont do the entire delete in one transaction. You may want to break it down into batches.

Finally, watch your tlog growth closely while doing the deletes. It can grow big pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

About how many tables are we talking that need to be archived?

If it's only one or a few tables, you could just run some SQL regularly via SQL Server Agent.

Something like this (very simplified):

```
-- copy to archive database
insert into ArchiveServer.dbo.ArchiveTable (Column1, Column2, ...)
select Column1, Column2, ...
from ProductionTableOnThisServer
where DateColumn < dateadd(m, -3, getdate())

-- delete in production database
delete from ProductionTableOnThisServer
where DateColumn < dateadd(m, -3, getdate())
```

In order for this example to work, it needs to be run on the production server **and** the archive server must be configured as a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) in the production server.

Of course this little example is far from perfect (or even production ready!).
This was just to express the basic idea.

In the real world, you probably also want to:

- wrap both queries together in a transaction so the real data doesn't get deleted if the archiving didn't work for some reason
- insert only the rows which are really new and update those which have changed
- and so on...